# T_RETURN error in php

Tags: php

I am unable to find my mistake. It says I have a T_RETURN error in line 34.

```
if ($type == 'post') {
$query = "INSERT INTO=Oktoberfest2013 (First Name, Last Name, Phone, Address, Department,Email Address, Level of Traning) 
VALUES ('$fname','$lname', '$phone', '$address', '$department', '$email', '$level')";
    if(!$mysqli->query($query))(
    return Errormessage: $mysqli->error);
```

The last line is line 34.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
require_once('config.php');
function connect() {
$mysqli = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_NAME, DB_PASS);

if( $mysqli->connect_error)
    {die('connect_error ('. $mysqli->connect_error .')' 
    . $mysqli->connect_error);

    }

    return $mysqli;
    }

Function insert ($types, $values) {
$mysqli = connect ();

if ($type == 'post') {
$query = "INSERT INTO=Oktoberfest2013 (First Name, Last Name, Phone, Address, Department,Email Address, Level of Traning) 
VALUES ('$fname','$lname', '$phone', '$address', '$department', '$email', '$level')";
    if(!$mysqli->query($query))(
    return Errormessage: $mysqli->error);

    }
   Function select ($query) {
mysqli = connect();

$result=$mysqli->query($query);

While ($obj=$result->fetch_object(:)(
    $result[] =$obj;)

    return $return

    ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if(!$mysqli->query($query))(
return Errormessage: $mysqli->error);
```

You have parentheses (..) instead of curly braces {..} surrounding your statement block. Since you want to return a string, the `return` statement should also be formatted as:

```
return 'Errormessage:'.$mysqli->error;
```

You have a similar issue with your `while` loop, coupled with more invalid syntax. Remove the `:` and replace the statement block delimiters with curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not valid PHP. You'll have to concatenate the result as a string to return it.

`return "Errormessage: " . $mysqli->error;`

And as w3d pointed out, you're using `(` instead of `{`.

Answer (score 1):

The line number that PHP reported is where it discovered the error, not necessarily where the error actually is; you have to examine the code leading up to that line.

```
if(!$mysqli->query($query))(
    return Errormessage: $mysqli->error);

    }
```

You need to consistently surround code blocks (groups of statements) with curly braces. Also, you are missing the double quotes around "Errormessage: $mysqli->error".

```
While ($obj=$result->fetch_object(:)(
```

There should not be just a colon inside the (already mismatched) parentheses.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO=Oktoberfest2013 (First Name, Last Name, Phone, Address, Department,Email Address, Level of Traning) 
VALUES ('$fname','$lname', '$phone', '$address', '$department', '$email', '$level')";
```

There appears to be a stray equals sign near the beginning of your SQL query. By the way, there is no reason to use PHP's variable interpolation to insert your values. You really should be using MySQLi's [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) feature to prevent [SQL injection](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).